# Do addons/extensions always run as the user of the extension?

Tags: google-apps-script

I know that webapps can run as the owner of the script, i'm considering moving some of my processes to extensions/addons, do they always run as the USER of the addon?

Comment: Yes, the person who installs the add-on uses their quota, and the add-on accesses the users account.  They must give permission for the add-on to use whatever Google Services are in the add-on.  The add-on user has no access to the account of the owner of the Apps Script file that the add-on is based on.  You will need to get the scopes authorized by Google to publish the add-on, unless it's published privately inside of a domain.  I wouldn't say that it's easy to get an add-on published.  You must provide some graphics of a specific size.

Comment: @Alan I think you can add it as a answer.

Comment: Thanks, I posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, the add-on runs from the account that installed the add-on.
- The add-on user does not have access to the server code in the add-on.  Client side code can always be viewed inside of the browser, just like any web app.
- The only thing that the add-on can access, that is owned by the
  account that created the add-on, is Script Properties.  But the add-on user
  can not see or access Script Properties through their code, or the
  code editor.
- The quota used goes against the account that installed the add-on.  For example, a free/consumer Google account has a quota of sending emails of only 100 recipients per day.
- The add-on accesses the users account, not the owner of the add-on.
- The account that installs the add-on must give permission for the
  add-on to use whatever Google Services are in the add-on.
- The add-on user has no access to the account of the owner of the Apps
  Script file that the add-on is based on.
- To publish the add-on publicly to the GSuite Marketplace, you will need to get the scopes authorized by Google, unless it's published privately inside of a domain, or you don't care if there is a warning message about it being unsafe, and you have fewer than 100 installations.

I wouldn't say that it's easy to get an add-on published. One thing that you must provide is some graphics of a specific size, with a transparent background.
You will also need to make sure that the user interface adheres to some basic guidelines.  There are many other requirements to publish an add-on.